# Filter json objects

Tags: json, logstash

Some of my logs contain json in their **message** field. I use the json filter as follow:

```
  json {
    skip_on_invalid_json => true
    source => "message"
    target => "json"
  }
```

To try to parse the **message** field, and if it contains valid json add it to the **json** field.
Unfortunately from time to time, I receive logs which contain a single string like `"some random message"` in the **message** field. In these logs the string from **message** end-up in the **json** and messes up the index mapping.

I htried to filter this out by adding:

```
  prune {
    blacklist_values => { "json" => "/.+/" }
  }
```

But this seems to always remove the **json** field.
Is there a way to parse the message field or keep the json field only when it contains an object and not a single string?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a ruby filter that tests the field you are interested in

```
    ruby {
        code => '
            s = event.get("json")
            if s and s.instance_of? String
                event.remove("json")
            end
        '
    }
```

That will not remove [json] if it is a hash or array.